# Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating member

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Getting the error of `Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating member` in my swift project and researched some answers and none seem to fix the problem in my context. Take A Look:
import UIKit

```
class PassionViewController: UIViewController {

   var factIndex = 0
   var counter = 1


    @IBOutlet var QuoteImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!

    let factBook = FactBook()
    let Liked = Favourite()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        funFactLabel.text = factBook.factsArray[factIndex]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBAction func showFunFact() {
        factIndex++
        if (factIndex >= factBook.factsArray.count) {
            self.factIndex = 0
        }
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.factsArray[factIndex]

        if counter == 36 {

            counter = 1

        } else {

          self.counter++

        }

        QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")

    }
    @IBAction func goBack() {
        factIndex--
        var number = factBook.factsArray.count-1
        if (factIndex < 0){
            self.factIndex = number


        }
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.factsArray[factIndex]
        if counter == 1 {

            counter = 36

        } else {

            self.counter--

        }

        QuoteImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).jpg")

    }
    @IBAction func Like() {


    let currentQuote = factBook.factsArray[factIndex]
           Liked.favouriteArray.append(currentQuote)
        }
    }
```

The `let currentQuote = factBook.factsArray[factIndex], factBook.factsArray` is retrieved from another view controller which is a array collection. `Liked.favouriteArray.append(currentQuote)` is to store this element into favouriteArray which is from a struct called Favourite:

```
import Foundation



struct Favourite {

    var favouriteArray:[String] = []








}
```

**However, the line Liked.favouriteArray.append(currentQuote) is generating the error: Immutable value of type '[String]' only has mutating member.** How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear because you didn't provide the `Favourite` type, but I assume it's either a `struct`, or it's a `class` that includes `factsArray` as a `let` variable. In either case, you're trying to modify a `let` variable, which is not allowed (mutating an immutable value). Either `liked` or `factsArray` must be `var`. (If `Favourite` is a `struct`, then `liked` must be `var` in either case.)

Note that Swift functions, methods, properties, and variables should start with a lowercase letter. Leading uppercase letters denote types.

Comment: However note that factsArray is a let and liked in a var.

Comment: `let Liked = Favourite()` is in the code above. That is going to make the entire struct (including its included array) be readonly, even if the underlying array is marked `var`.

Comment: Removed The Error Works like a charm thanks! You deserve that 117K rep.